# coffescript a range of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

i'm trying to get a range of various inputs and i have no clue to do this on coffee, thank's for any tip.

and if i write another input on the script the first one did not work.

```
previewBoxWidth = 256
previewBoxHeight = 180

createUploadWithPreviewBox = (container, counter) ->
  #create preview box and file field and appending it to container
  input = $("<input type='file' id='f1' name='user[f1]'>")
  input = $("<input type='file' id='l1' name='photo[l2]'>")


  preview = $('<div>').addClass 'preview-container'
  preview.append input
  container.append preview
```

Comment: what the... html code inside jquery constructor?

Comment: (function() {
  var createUploadWithPreviewBox, previewBoxHeight, previewBoxWidth;

  previewBoxWidth = 256;

  previewBoxHeight = 180;

  createUploadWithPreviewBox = function(container, counter) {
    var input, preview;

    input = $("<input type='file' name='[]'>");
    preview = $('<div>').addClass('preview-container');
    preview.append(input);
    container.append(preview);
    return input.bind('change', function(evt) {
      var files, targetInput;

     
  };

  $(function() {
    return createUploadWithPreviewBox($('#upload-container'), 0);
  });

}).call(this);

Comment: no, what i mean is: why do you have html code inside the jquery selector? i didn't know you can do that. maybe you can't.

Comment: is the coffeescript that come with rails

Comment: * i don't think you can have jquery selectors like that (it doesn't matter which version of coffeescript). it's supposed be a proper css selector.

Comment: @celwell: `$(a_string_of_html)` is fine: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: Do you want `input` to contain both `<input>`s?

Comment: humm.. is just to get any input file type of the page!

Comment: sorry mu a string of html, i did not get it

Comment: and if leave just the input it not save

Comment: What is `container`? What you're doing should get you one `<input>` inside `container` so it should sort of work as long as `container` is on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Cd4JR/

Comment: container is for preview the image.

Comment: thank's mu, i'm kind figuring out this

Comment: but in any case, dont have any way to this script grab any input type file? without the need to pass the name and id?

Comment: It's worth noting that the `$` function also takes an object of attributes so you could have `$('<input>', type: file, id: 'f1', name: 'user[f1]')`, which is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1):

```
preview = $('<div>').addClass 'preview-container'

input = $("<input type='file' id='f1' name='user[f1]'>")
preview.append input
input = $("<input type='file' id='l1' name='photo[l2]'>")
preview.append input

container.append preview
```

Comment: you were overwriting the 'input' variable so it only equaled the second value by the time you appended it to preview

Comment: right, just one thing, have a way to get any input type file?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question. you could use two different variables instead of 'input' for both. maybe: input_user and input_photo. then you would be able to reference the variables later. or you could use $('#f1') and $('#l1') to get the jquery objects again.

Comment: humm... well, i gonna try it, because your solution have just one minor problem, the 2 inputs still showing and don't know upload in one field but not on another